# Creating a bar plot with a single vector with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Creating a `barplot` from a single vector/column in a `.csv` file is no problem in vanilla R:

```
msgs <- read.csv(file = "C:/my/csv/file.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

barplot(table(msgs$Author))
```

This code produces following `barplot`:

[image]

Though, I am having a hard time replicating this with the `ggplot2` package. To do it with a `qplot()`, this code works:

```
qplot(as.factor(msgs$Author), geom="bar")
```

But I need it as a `ggplot()`, which I can't seem to make work. I have tried:

```
ggplot() + 
aes(table(msgs$Author)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .75, ill = "tomato3")
```

(which didn't work at all) and

```
ggplot(msgs, aes(x = Author, y = Timestamp)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .75, fill = "tomato3")
```

The above snippet *does* show correct result with the bars

[image]

but the y-axis is all wrong. I don't want Timestamp to be the y-axis, but rather the amount of times every Author shows up in the vector/column.

I can't really find a way of providing `ggplot()` with a single column or vector though. Can any of you help me with this?

**EDIT:** The data below can be used to reproduce my dataset. It is not the exact values, but the format is all that is needed.

```
Timestamp,Author
1534334332013,user1
1534334331252,user2
1534333113577,user2
1534333112754,user3
1529160743306,user4
1528886271012,user3
1528886269171,user5
1528886261391,user5
1526477321297,user5
1526477320773,user4
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of output?

Comment: Sample of output? Are the images I've posted not satisfactory?
Edit: I see that the images were formatted poorly. That has been fixed now.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example of your data, so that we can replicate your code. Something like `dput(msgs)` if you can.

Comment: I have added a version of my dataset, which can be used to reproduce the dataset. I can't share the exact dataset since it contains personal info.

Comment: `ggplot(data = msgs,aes(x = Author)) + geom_bar()` should suffice. `geom_bar` is for when you data isn't already aggregated into counts, but instead the heights should represent frequency counts of a variable. If you already *have* the frequency counts, use `geom_col`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I produced similar example:

```
xxx <- rpois(1000, 10)
xtable <- table(xxx)

ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = as.numeric(names(xtable)), y = as.numeric(xtable))) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .75)
```

This should produce you correct answer.

Comment: By manipulating the answer a bit to take size of strings into account, I made it work. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `geom_bar` layer will count observations for you if you just leave off the `y` aesthetic. For example

```
ggplot(msgs, aes(Author)) + geom_bar()
```

Tested with

```
msgs <- read.csv(text="Timestamp,Author
  1534334332013,user1
  1534334331252,user2
  1534333113577,user2
  1534333112754,user3
  1529160743306,user4
  1528886271012,user3
  1528886269171,user5
  1528886261391,user5
  1526477321297,user5
  1526477320773,user4")
```

Produces

[image]